# Display two consecutive rows with a background color for AG-Grid with Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I want to display 2 rows with same background color. For e.g. row 1 and row 2 needs to have background color light grey; row 3 and row 4 needs to have white background; again row 5 and row 6 will have a grey background. Is there a way we can achieve this based on row data ?

Sample grid data **:**

```
[{
  id: null,
  duplicateFor: 123,
  name: 'abc',
},
 {
   id: 123,
   duplicateFor: null,
   name: 'def',
 },
 {
   id: null,
   duplicateFor: 456,
   name: 'xyz',
 },
 {
   id: 456,
   duplicateFor: null,
   name: 'qwe',
 }]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Vue Data Grid: Row Styles](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/row-styles/)

```html
<template>
  <ag-grid-vue
    style="width: 600px; height: 500px"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    :columnDefs="columnDefs"
    :rowData="rowData"
    :getRowStyle="getRowStyle"
  >
  </ag-grid-vue>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 // ...data, components etc
methods: {
    getRowStyle: params => {
      return (params.node.rowIndex) % 4 < 2 ? { background: 'red' } : { background: 'blue' }
    }  
  }
}
</script>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-vue-example-forked-gcr4fl?file=/src/App.vue:1252-1396)